# Pandas Split Series of List of Lists to Find Word Count/Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter

I have a dataframe of tweets over the past 24 hrs grouped by dt.datetime hour, where each row is a **list of lists** for the tweets during that hour. **My goal here** is to split and flatten these tweets for each row so I can filter out stop words (the, a, but), and get a word frequency count of tweets for each hour. My actual data has 2-3k tweets for each hour, so because the end goal would be to group the data in the below format, I would also need to filter the count of words by the top 10-15 highest counts.

df =

```
      hour     tweets
0     1:00     ["['this darn tweet'], ['tweet']"]
1     2:00     ["['another tweet'], ['tweet'], ['tweet']"]
2     3:00     ["['this tweet'], ['this tweet']"]
3     4:00     ["['tweet'], ['this tweet']"]
4     5:00     ["['tweet'], ['another tweet'], ['yet another tweet'], ['tweet']"]
```

Because this grouped hourly data is in a dataframe and not a list, the only way that I can think of doing this is some form of Series.split() - which yields me the error:

```
[in]:
df['tweets'] = [tweet.Series.split() for tweet in df['tweets']]
[out]:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My research into this error has gone deep, and I can't seem to find any examples of splitting on a series of list of lists, but I suspect it's some form of list comprehension.

## Expected result:

```
      hour     tweet  this     another   darn   yet
0     1:00     2      1        0         1      0
1     2:00     3      1        1         0      0
2     3:00     2      2        0         0      0
3     4:00     2      1        0         0      0
4     5:00     4      0        2         0      1
```

Comment: What is the `type` of `df['tweets'][0]`?

Comment: df['tweets'] would be of dtype: object

Comment: I need to the know the output of `type(df['tweets'][0])`?

Comment: Ah my mistake: <class 'list'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try:

```
stopwords = ['the', 'a', 'but']

# extract all the words from list of string
words = df['tweets'].str[0].str.extractall(r'(\w+)')[0]

# Remove stopwords and create frequency table
table = words[~words.isin(stopwords)].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)

# join with hour column
df[['hour']].join(table)
```

**Details:**

First extract all the words from the `tweets` column using **[`.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html)**:

```
   match
0  0           this
   1           darn
   2          tweet
   3          tweet
1  0        another
   1          tweet
   2          tweet
   3          tweet
2  0           this
   1          tweet
   2           this
   3          tweet
3  0          tweet
   1           this
   2          tweet
4  0          tweet
   1        another
   2          tweet
   3            yet
   4        another
   5          tweet
   6          tweet
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Then use boolean masking to remove the `stopwords` from the above extracted words and use **[`.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)** to encode the words into indicator/dummy variables. After encoding the words take **[`.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)** on `level=0` to get the counts of each word per `hour`:

```
   another  darn  this  tweet  yet
0        0     1     1      2    0
1        1     0     0      3    0
2        0     0     2      2    0
3        0     0     1      2    0
4        2     0     0      4    1
```

Finally **[`.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)** the above frequency table with `hour` column to get the desired result:

```
   hour  another  darn  this  tweet  yet
0  1:00        0     1     1      2    0
1  2:00        1     0     0      3    0
2  3:00        0     0     2      2    0
3  4:00        0     0     1      2    0
4  5:00        2     0     0      4    1
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I realized that since the index for ```table``` was already my hour, I didn't need to perform the join, just reset the index to ```table['hourindex'] = table.index```

Comment: @GeordiAlm Glad i could help. Happy coding!

Comment: for anyone else that may come across this, would you know how to sort this result (the columns) by maximum values? ```df.ix[:, df.max().sort_values(ascending=False).index]``` results in a type error the timestamp and int.

Comment: @GeordiAlm Let's discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)

Comment: You can use `df.iloc[:, np.argsort(df.max() * -1)]` or `df.loc[:, df.max().sort_values(ascending=False).index]` after setting the `hour` column as `index`.

Comment: This morning after running another test, I'm realizing that ```df['tweets'].str[0]``` performs the str.extract on only the first list in the list of lists, so the list of words extracted are a subset of words from the first list in each list of list hour groupings. The correct format would be ```df['tweets'].str[0:24].str.extractall(r'(\w+)')[0]``` - but it looks like ```Series.str.extract()``` doesn't understand how to unpack this, as it yields a null dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't the full solution and it's detailed (which means it can be cleaned up a bit, but your iterating over a series of rows that have lists of lists, so I took this step by step to see what was happing.

There may be regex way to remove all the punctuation and brackets first, and then it'd be easier to loop. So if anyone out there understands regex on a series, that'd be helpful.

You can do your word count on the list, then find unique by sending the list to a set() and making a new list.

```
tweets = ["['this darn tweet'], ['tweet']"]
print(type(tweets)
list_of_words = []
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet)
    print(type(tweet))
    print(tweet.replace('\'','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',',''))
    tweet_stripped = tweet.replace('\'','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',','')
    print(tweet_stripped.split())
    for word in tweet_stripped.split():
        print(word)
        list_of_words.append(word)
print(list_of_words)
```

Here's the string of ouptuts. You can see how you start with a list, so you need handle that like a list, then each you operate on a string, collecting the words

```
<class 'list'>
['this darn tweet'], ['tweet']
<class 'str'>
this darn tweet tweet
['this', 'darn', 'tweet', 'tweet']
this
darn
tweet
tweet
['this', 'darn', 'tweet', 'tweet']
```

To iterate over the series, you'll need to wrap all that above in your series loop
something like

```
for r in df['tweets']:
    #insert above routine here
```